# Windows tool to trigger Shutdown/Sleep based on fan failure or excess temperature

Tags: windows-10, monitoring, hardware

My laptop's fan sometimes stops working, but works after shutdown/sleep.

I'm looking for a software that will shutdown/sleep my PC if the fan has stopped working or if the PC's temperature exceeds certain value.

Prefer open source software, but not mandatory.